# QGIS committedAttributeValuesChanges signal never emitted

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to use QgsVectorLayer committedAttributeValuesChanges signal (on a non geometry layer) but it is never emitted. committedFeaturesAdded and committedFeaturesRemoved signals are emitted but committedAttributeValuesChanges never. Does anybody face the same issue and/or know how to fix it ?

I'm using QGIS 2.8

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The same issue existed for the commitedGeometriesChanges signal which was discussed in detail on the developer mailing list [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.qgis.devel/36586).  The signals do almost the same thing so it is probably the same bug.

TL;DR: upgrade to 2.8.2 or higher.